# iOS 9.3.1 Xcode 7.3 "Unable to copy symbols from this device"

Tags: ios, xcode

I was using Xcode 7.2 but then I upgraded my iPhone to iOS 9.3.1 and got the message "Could not find Developer Disk Image".  I've seen this many times in my life so I upgraded to Xcode 7.3.  Now I get "Unable to copy symbols from this device"  I tried the beta seed as well.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delete app from your device if is installed. Try to reconnect your device and wait for copying symbolic files symbol to complete the process, than clean your project, and relaunch Xcode.

**Edit**
Ensure you have enough space on your mac

Answer (score 8):

I was using the Xcode 9.1 beta and iOS 11.1, I got the error message from the Xcode while running the project.

here's an error message:
`Unable to copy symbols from this device`

I did following steps:

```
1. Quit the Xcode.
2. Delete the app from the device.
3. Delete "iOS DeviceSupport" the Symbols of iOS device from the following path: `~/Library/Developer` 
4. see the image.
```

[image]

```
5. Again, connect the device and it will copy all symbols again.
```

It will work.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have another data point. At least in my case, it was due to operator error. I can confirm that if you update the iOS version on the phone, you will likely get a message saying [iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316373/xcode-9-iphone-is-busy-preparing-debugger-support-for-iphone). I was impatient and clicked "Cancel", which is absolutely the wrong thing to do! That might result in the error above (it did in my case).

XCode needs to download symbols and other support files in "iOS Device Support". For iOS 11.4, it's about 2GB, so it will take several minutes to download (your mileage may vary). Just be patient and it will eventually work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

ios 12. xcode Version 10.0 (10A255)

I try to

- restart xcode and
- delete "iOS DeviceSupport".
- delete app from my ios

They all dont work.

I just restart my iphone, and the error disappear.

Comment: iPhone restart solved the problem for me too.  iOS12.2, Xcode 10.2.1 on macOS 10.14.5