# Fixing Xcode 9 issue: "iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I'm looking for more information on the message below. Xcode 9 seems to be hanging for a couple minutes already...

**How can I tell Xcode 9 to quickly recognize my previously used device updated to iOS 11?**

> .Alex’s iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for .Alex’s iPhone
> Xcode will continue when .Alex’s iPhone is finished.

[image: Xcode screenshot for above error message]

Comment: I restarted the phone and waited for 1 min and then it worked.

Comment: I rebooted my phone and restarted XCode multiple times and it didn't help. I t worked after I rebooted my mac.

Comment: This happened to my after I performed an iOS update on my iPhone 6. The progress bar at the top of the Xcode window should show the progress of whatever is going on in the background. I believe all it's doing is to load in crash logs/symbols/etc.... same as what happens every time you update the OS on your iDevice.

Answer (score 762, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this:

**Solution 1:** Patiently wait for 10 to 15 minutes. Have a tea or roam around ;-)

**Solution 2:** Disconnect device from the system. Restart both iPhone and Xcode and then rebuild again.

**Solution 3:**

1. Go to Windows → Devices and Simulators (Shortcut key: cmd+shift+2)

   [image: Step 1]
2. You’ll see iPhone device connected to system with message

   > iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone
3. Click on plus button (+) present in bottom-left corner.

   [image: Step2-3]
4. This will show the device connected to system. Click on Next button.

   [image: Step 4]
5. Thereafter you’ll see ‘device setup was successful’. Click on Done button.

   [image: Step 5]

*Solution 3 worked for me!*

**Solution 4:**

Unpair your device and then pair it again. Thereafter  follow Step 3.

Comment: Solution 3 is amazing. You might want to add that after step 5, you need to click "Cancel Running" and run again; it then runs instantly.

Comment: You might want to check (on your iPhone) for trust issues, under: Settings > General > Profile & Device Management.

Comment: This iOS ecosystem has so many problems. I am just starting to learn and the first month has been solving bugs of macOS, iOS and xCode.

Comment: @PrimožKralj : These problems are with others as well i.e. Android, Tizen etc. Once the problem is identified it is fixed in next version. There exists no product which is 100% bug free!

Comment: Solution #2 worked for me but I also unplugged the phone from my computer and after the phone rebooted and I entered the passcode I then replugged it in and then when I started Xcode everything was good.

Comment: Well only waiting for 20 minutes helped. So need keep the patience :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Solution #3 worked instantly. I just had to click “cancel running” BEFORE. This was annoying me for almost a year, then I thought Apple fixed this ridiculous bug (I send them feedback, and I am sure many others did, too…) but…

Comment: For me : #3 alone didn't work, #2 alone didn't work, #3 after #2 worked.

Comment: Solution #1 worked for me :D ! At first I thought I just had to wait but it only actually worked after I made myself some tea ! Thanks for the tip

Comment: You already waited for 5 mins... you searched for the issue for the next 5... you applied in the next 5... 15 mins already elapsed... solution 1 == solution 3

Comment: None of the above solutions worked. Tried them all. Then I unpaired the device as  tounaobun suggested, after that I was finally able to continue.

Comment: also make sure that you don't have proxy tools on. I had this issue when Charles was on.

Comment: #3 via USB after iOS13 Update :)

Comment: If all 3 solutions don't work, go for unpairing the iPhone (see answer by @David Dal Busco) and then immediately go for solution 3

Comment: what about if I get the same issue but I don't see the warning in Xcode?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey it's 5 years later and I'm still running into the same issues with Mac/iOS setup as people have been having for at least that long. It's definitely not "fixed in next version". I've also spent at least a month trying to get Mac building of mobile apps working with just endless issues punctuated by days lacking progress.

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me on iOS 17.1! 

Answer (score 229):

I clicked ‘Cancel Running’, opened the Devices list, unpaired my iPhone, removed my USB cable and reconnected it, paired the iPhone, and then was asked on my iPhone to enter my passcode ("pin code"). Did this and then was finally able to pair my phone correctly.

Comment: Didn't need to restart the iPhone.  Made sure the home screen stayed on, unpaired the iPhone, unplugged the USB and plugged it back in.  Clicked the Trust button on the iPhone and it's good to go.

Comment: I did not have to make sure the home screen stayed on, worked fine just following the steps in the answer.

Comment: I had have to answer on iTunes trusty question, succeed only after answering

Comment: Unpairing and re-pairing worked.  (This Xcode option is in Windows -> Devices and Simulators.)

Comment: this worked after I tried 3 times, so perhaps Solution #1 above (to simply wait) is the only working solution.

Answer (score 60):

Wait a few minutes. The application will start automatically

Comment: And it only happened the first time.
I googled my way here because I had that issue but it only happened the first time I tried to launch the application. It hasn't happened again for 3 days.

Answer (score 34):

**Restarting Xcode worked for me (quit and start again).**

What didn't work for me:

- waiting for an hour on one device
- waiting for an hour on another device
- restarting devices
- unpairing/pairing devices

Comment: restarting then unpairing/pairing device worked for me

Comment: unpairing works if stuck on fetching debug symbols

Answer (score 17):

It turns out XCode opens device manager window beneath it and waits for you to hit the next button. Switch to that window, hit next and you get the progress bar for the process to show up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had to go to WINDOW > Devices & Simulators in Xcode and saw that it was busy processing.  That was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

In my case, iTunes was open, so

1 - open iTunes

2 - access you phone

[image]

3 - click to disconnect your phone
[image]

Now the device is ready on XCode

[image]

Hope it helps....

Comment: Closing iTunes "There is a software update available for your iPhone" dialog solved the issue for me.

Comment: if you don't want to listen your music during the development, close it will do the job @ErickA.Montañez =)

Comment: @ErickA.Montañez that means iOS didn't update properly, you should download and install that update (backup first)

Answer (score 13):

below solution worked for me, follow steps to resolve your issue:

**Step 1**: **Cancel Running**

**Step 2** : open Window menu and select **Devices and Simulators**

**Step 3** : **Unpair** the iPhone

**Step 4** : Removed iPhone **USB cable** and **reconnect** to the system

**Step 5** : Pair the iPhone when you connect then you will be asked to Trust or Don't Allow, Please click Truct on your iPhone and enter your passcode (Pin Code)

**Note** : I performed all the above steps they worked for me. The issue of my device debugger gone.

Below is the Screenshot of **Devices and Simulators** Menu

[image]

Answer (score 12):

On your iPhone:

Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted Computers

Wait a few seconds, it's all.

Answer (score 10):

I unplugged my cable and saw this. After it reached the end I was able to run it no problems.

[image: Xcode screenshot of status bar showing "Preparing debugger support"]

You don't have to unplug to see this; just hit cancel and you will see its progress.

Comment: That was a good hint. At first I didn't see this bar. So I figured; if you don't see any progress bar, unpair the phone and try again.

Answer (score 8):

1. Click on Window menu
2. Select Device and Simulators
3. Select your device
4. Click on + button at bottom left corner
5. Click Next
6. Click Done

Answer (score 5):

I found deleting the app from the device and re-installing with Xcode solved this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using my iPhone X to debug **via Network** and suddenly had this problem.

**Disable "Connect via network"** and try again with USB. 
This trick worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I realised I had less than 100 MBs of free space on my disc. Freeing up disk space solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution:

- Open Window -> Devices and Simulators
- Unpair iPhone on the side list
- Unplug and plug again the USB cable
- Press Trust in the prompt message in the device!
- Then it should work! It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem many times, these things worked for me:

- restarting my phone + xCode.
- checking that both your Mac and your iPhone are connected to the same Network.( has a high potential ).
- repairing my phone.

Answer (score 3):

When you plug a New device which is having iOS 11, Xcode 9 will Prepare Debugger Support for that device, At this time you should **Wait** to complete it.

Then run the project in that device it will run smoothly.

If you didn't keep patience while creating Debugger Support then it will throw the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: This worked: just wait a few minutes to let the process complete.

Comment: Yes, Try to be calm or have a cup of coffee at that time 

Comment: This doesn't always worked. Xcode "Processed" the device for 2 hours, no actual progress.

Comment: @christophercotton In which Xcode, it did not worked?

Comment: @R.Mohan in Xcode 11.6 and Xcode 12 beta2. Trying to use an iOS9 device, iPod touch.

Answer (score 3):

**The Best way:**

1. Disconnect the Iphone.
2. Clean xcode by command+ shift + k or by going to Product -> Clean

Connect again

Run again

Answer (score 3):

My setup

- macOS 10.14.6
- iOS 13.2.3
- Xcode 11.2

Tried all the "speedrun" tips up till 2019-11-24 without luck.
The wait seemed inevitable but incredibly long in my case:

#### with a freshly upgraded iOS version.

I then found this comment on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/6gfarv/question_xcode_9_stuck_on_preparing_debugger/) which makes the most sense:

> This is required when you connect a device with an iOS version that
>   the respective computer's Xcode didn't see before. It saves them in
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport and it does
>   take a while. Don't restart Xcode as it will not help you, just wait
>   for it to finish.
>
> It takes quite some time because these debugger
>   support files occupy a lot of space (29 GB for me), though you can
>   safely delete any version from there, and if you connect a device with
>   that version again, it will re-save it from scratch.

So if you just upgraded your iOS, then the "from scratch" part could take longer than usual, also depending on your network condition. In my case, it is definitely much much longer than the "10-15min" other people claimed. I measure it by hours.

A lot of tricks seem to have worked but they neglect the fact that time goes on as you try things while Xcode keeps working on the setup in the background, and quite possibly resumes its job whenever you do a restart/reboot cycle.

This led me to noticing that my Xcode version is just one step behind the iOS point release. After upgrading my Xcode, it worked.

**But it took longer because I removed the iOS DeviceSupport folder by following a tip!**

#### So here are my suggestions:

- Check your Xcode version down to the minor version to make sure it should actually support the iOS version.
- Check your Mac's free disk space to make room for newly generated device support content under `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` as [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48475629/987846) suggested.
- Check if you have connected your device to a fast-enough USB port, as [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47270992/987846) suggests.
- Wait till Xcode finishes "preparing for debugging".
- If it doesn't finish in a few seconds or minutes, keep waiting.
- DO NOT remove any folder as [some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56686640/987846) may suggest. Removal would simply make you wait longer!

Comment: I think Xcode 11.3.1 is broken. Had problems with multiples devices after the update.

Answer (score 2):

rebooted iPhone, closed all other open applications and unlocked phone worked

Answer (score 2):

Clean : <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> is what works for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me it Worked after following the below steps

**Step-1** Go to Devices and Simulator

[image]

**Step-2** Deselect Show as run destination and Connect via network Options

[image]

Wait for Few seconds to Load the **Xcode**, If you want you can restart Xcode also.

**Step-3**  Follow the same steps and got to Devices and Simulators

Tick back both the options and it will be normal to install your app back.

Answer (score 2):

Do this Two Task to solve your problem:

`First` Go to Xcode then -> Preferences -> Accounts then below click the plus icon to add apple id it must me same as your iphone device apple id.

`Second` Just change the cable if first solution can not work

Answer (score 1):

I updated to iOS 11.0.3 then the error appeared. After restarting my iPhone and XCode, it showed "Could not launch the app", so I navigated to the phone's device management to trust, then it solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I hadn't given iTunes permissions to run on the computer.  (I don't use iTunes for music, so I had foolishly just hit "decline" in annoyance whenever the EULA dialog box came up.)

Comment: Please provide answers only. No opinions or I feel with you like answers

Answer (score 1):

- Unpaired my iPhone
- Removed my USB cable and reconnected it (Do make sure that you unplugged the USB and plugged it back in)
- Paired the iPhone.

(3 important steps)

Answer (score 1):

### **Xcode 10.3 Solution**

The following error messages apply:

> iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone 
>   Xcode will continue when iPhone is finished.
>
> An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (The service is invalid.) 
>   Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000022).

---

Follow the steps in [Jayprakash Dubey's post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47448911/7443472)

and

- Close Xcode;
- Delete contents of DerivedData folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Restart Xcode & iPhone
- Pair Xcode & iPhone again
- & run application

Answer (score 1):

Today, I have faced the issue and tried out everything mentioned here and different pages as well. Nothing worked for me.

Lastly, I have reset the iPhone, then tried building the application and finally it worked for me.

Comment: Phone reset and removing the pin code worked for me after wasting over 3 hours trying everything else from the other answers

Answer (score 1):

I spent like 10 or more hours trying all the answers and none worked for me!
From [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/692230) can be read this too:

> This usually means that Xcode is busy copying debug symbols from the
> device. This can be impacted by...

But it worked for the other, newer phone, so my issue was located to a question: "why XCode can't copy..." - whatever he needs?

- because it is an error at the motherboard around the microphone, not the device itself, and that's why some apps are working, like registering a video ( without sound) and other apps like Talking Tom not.
  I have changed the phone owner, changed the privacy settings, unlugged, unpaired, rebooted: none worked. -and on that phone it will work after the motherboard it is replaced.

So sometimes can be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion when I open the details:

Please delete apps signed with your free account from this device to remain under the limit.

So I've deleted 1 app from the iPhone, then the new app installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my iPhone to the latest version 11.0.3, then restarted my iPhone. Restarted my XCode 9. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for solution with Apple TV, I just experience the exact problem "Apple TV is busy: Preparing debugger support for Apple TV” with Apple TV 4K with my Macbook Air (Early 2015)

The solution is not to unpair or restart devices. But to switch network. I brought it to a faster and more open network and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Settings > General > Profile & Device Management > (Under DEVELOPER APP category) click my email address that happens to be my Apple ID > Trust Developer**

This might not be relevant to anyone else, as I am new to iOS development and this was my first attempt to install an application on my phone, but I'll provide the answer as it wasn't yet listed.

I went through restarting my phone, restarting Xcode, unplugging and plugging back in, clean building, and even removed the device from the Devices and Simulators menu. However, I believe the cause for me was that I hadn't added my developer certificate to the listed of trusted certificates on my device.

I am on iOS 10.3.3 so the navigation and wording in Settings on the phone might be slightly different, but the final step I took before this issue was fixed was to trust my developer certificate as an individual developer on my phone.

To do that, go **Settings > General > Profile & Device Management > (Under DEVELOPER APP category) click my email address that happens to be my Apple ID > Trust Developer**

Whether or not that was the cause of my problem, I am unsure. This was, however, the last step that I took before the app ran on my phone successfully after doing all of the other steps listed above.

Answer (score 0):

If running beta software and you update the OS, make sure to get the latest Xcode beta also. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I left AppCode open while Xcode was trying to process the device, closing it solved the problem. Maybe can be one of the possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on macOS 10.14.5 using Xcode 10.2.1. After none of the solution here worked for me I restarted the Mac and this did the trick...

Comment: Didn't work for me: iOS 13.2.3, macOS 10.14.6, Xcode 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem because of a cable. I changed my third party USB/lighting cable into original Apple cable, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**
Solution : Shutdown your Apple Watch [x], unplug cable and then plug it again.
Reason: You can try this solution if you don't develop an apple watch application, because Xcode is looking for an apple watch developer sdk. **

Thinking it would be apple watch related, I turned off the watch, then restarted my phone for all connections to be closed. This way, I was able to connect to my phone without any problems. but a few days ago I was desperately turning my phone off and on while trying to fix this problem. the problem was not fixed. Instead of checking the devices, I think it is necessary to focus on what the problem is. Apple officials have to explain something about this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was my apple watch that caused the issue. Xcode was trying to pair with my watch, but didnt seem to succeed.

So i disconnected my watch by turning off bluethooth, after that the problem was solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34369543)

Answer (score -1):

The 'Continue' button is under the error message.
Just hit 'Enter'

You should confirm that the device was listed on my 'Managed Devices' on Apple @ https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

Answer (score -2):

Solution1:

- In Xcode Goto window>Devices and Simulators. you will see the connected device busy processing
- Just remove the USB and connect again.

Solution2:
Restarting the device will also solve problem.

Solution3:
Wait for 4 to 5 minutes will also works.

Answer (score -4):

There seem to be a lot of issues related to the same error. For me it was the applications which I've installed from another iMac whose files where not present on my MacBook so Xcode was not able to find the files making the debugger to wait forever!

**Solution**: Deleting all the application which I've installed from the iMac helped me solve the problem.