# Preparing debugger support for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, virtual-machine

I cant install he app on iphone i'm stuck on this message.

> "Preparing debugger support for iPhone"

[Tried all answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316373/xcode9-iphone-is-busy-preparing-debugger-support-for-iphone) and still nothing.

It is followed by itunes could not connect to iphone or whatever...

I'm using a virtual mac machine.

Comment: "I'm using a virtual mac machine" So you're using some unsupported configuration? This is a how to use your computer question, not a programming question.

Comment: Deployment of the app has everything to do with programming as well as IDE configuration so if you have no information useful just ignore my post.

Comment: Deployment of the app, yes. But how to use an unsupported configuration, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of research and useless downvotes i got the tiny trouble.
My virtualbox was configured to connect the devices over USB 1.0

As soon as i installed extensions pack and switched to USB 2.0 the app started deploying.

Answer (score 13):

For me, the following worked:
On iphone open Settings -> Developer -> Clear Trusted Computers.
Then disconnect and reconnect the iphone. Confirm that you trust this computer. After that, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Using macOS High Sierra. 
I had my app working by going to my iPhone to configure.

**Settings > General > Device Management > Click Trust "(Developer Apps)"**

Answer (score 0):

My setup

- macOS 10.14.6
- iOS 13.2.3
- Xcode 11.2

Tried all the "speed-it-up" tips up till 2019-11-24 without luck.
The wait seemed inevitable but incredibly long in my case:

#### with a freshly upgraded iOS version.

I then found this comment on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/6gfarv/question_xcode_9_stuck_on_preparing_debugger/) which makes the most sense:

> This is required when you connect a device with an iOS version that
>   the respective computer's Xcode didn't see before. It saves them in
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport and it does
>   take a while. Don't restart Xcode as it will not help you, just wait
>   for it to finish.
>
> It takes quite some time because these debugger
>   support files occupy a lot of space (29 GB for me), though you can
>   safely delete any version from there, and if you connect a device with
>   that version again, it will re-save it from scratch.

So if you just upgraded your iOS, then the "from scratch" part could take longer than usual, also depending on your network condition. In my case, it is definitely much much longer than the "10-15min" other people claimed. I measure it by hours.

A lot of tricks seem to have worked but they neglect the fact that time goes on as you try things while Xcode keeps working on the setup in the background, and quite possibly resumes its job whenever you do a restart/reboot cycle.

This led me to noticing that my Xcode version is just one step behind the iOS point release. After upgrading my Xcode, it worked.

**But it took longer because I removed the iOS DeviceSupport folder by following a tip!**

#### So here are my suggestions:

- Check your Xcode version down to the minor version to make sure it should actually support the iOS version.
- Check your Mac's free disk space to make room for newly generated device support content under `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` as [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48475629/987846) suggested.
- Check if you have connected your device to a fast-enough USB port, as the accepted answer of this question suggests.
- Wait till Xcode finishes "preparing for debugging".
- If it doesn't finish in a few seconds or minutes, keep waiting.
- DO NOT remove any folder as [some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56686640/987846) may suggest. Removal would simply make you wait longer!