# iphone is busy: waiting for device, xcode will continue when iphone is finished

Tags: xcode

This error occurred when I used the Iphone for debugging.I've tried restarting the Iphone and mac,but it hasn't worked.

[image]

Comment: You can find some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316373

Answer (score 1):

way1: Restart XCode :)
way2: Enable background app fetch on iPhone (disable low-power mode)

Answer (score 0):

I had to click the small yellow hammer on the top bar on xcode and set it to the new build setting (rather than legacy build)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was these steps:

1. Unplug device cable
2. Restart Xcode
3. Plug device back in with cable
4. Run app while still having this issue

At this point I just waited a few seconds and then the error went away, before also completing the build and running the app successfully on the device.