# Xcode can't build to physical iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have been able to build my projects to my iPad air as recently as last week, however, after I tried to turn on `connect via network` it seems that either the iPad or Xcode has entered a corrupted state.

When connected to Xcode -> window -> devices and simulators
[image]
This message `<device name> is busy: Preparing debugger support for <device name>` will never go away.

When trying to build the project while usb cable is attached:
[image]

But it will never finish...

Xcode Version: `10.2.1 (10E1001)`

iPad air model: `MD788KN/A`

iPad Software version: `12.3.1`

I have tried rebooting the iPad without any change in behavior, I have also tried to reset all settings `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings` still no change in behavior.

I have an iPhone 5, another iPad air + an iPad pro frequently connected to my machine with this instance of Xcode. Neither of these devices have any troubles connection or building.

EDIT: and btw, tried the solution from here: [Xcode 9 "iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316373/xcode-9-iphone-is-busy-preparing-debugger-support-for-iphone/46420487)

this have been going on for a few days now. waiting 10-15 more minutes will not help.

Some times after rebooting iPad and restarting Xcode I will get past the "waiting for debugger" but instead I will see this error [image]
Even though I have unlocked the device... iTunes even acknowledge it as unlocked and are able to look into the device. Xcode on the other hand still believes that is is locked.

Comment: Can you build tethered?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I mean not wireless, with Build Via Network turned back off.

Comment: Oh right. Nope unfortunately not. Have tried to disable the "connect via network" option and build through the cable but it never finishes waiting for debugger support

Comment: Hmm, I would try deleting the mobile device support files.

Comment: I will give that a try. Do you happen to know where I would find these files on a Mac ?

Comment: I was thinking of the ones in _~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS Device Support_.

Comment: Yep. That did the trick! Thanks

Comment: Hmm. You didn’t find that suggestion anywhere?  Maybe I should give it as an answer?

Comment: This solution was not it the thread I referred to - and not on the first 2 pages on google results based on my search. Please provide it as an answer.

Comment: Ok answered it on the other question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56686640/341994, so as not to multiply duplicates unnecessarily.

Comment: Agreed. Will upvote it on the orignial thread

Comment: And let’s delete this one please. Thanks.