# AppleTv is busy: Copying cache files from device Xcode will continue when AppleTv is finished

Tags: xcode, macos, tvos, apple-tv, pairing

I have been trying to pair appleTv to my MAC through Xcode.
I have tried with three different networks. One of which is completely dedicated to my project. In other words, I am the only one using it.

I have tried for hours on end. Reset the appleTv, closed and reopened both the Mac and the appleTv, tried three different networks and the result is always the same.

> AppleTv is busy: Copying cache files from device
>
> Xcode will continue when AppleTv is finished.

I have no idea what to try next. I have wasted countless hours doing something that should be straightforward and I am totally unable to make any progress in my project.

Any help is welcome.

---

**NOTE:** In the days before, whenever the pairing works, it stops working if I leave the AppleTv untouched for a long period of time(hours). It appears as "Disconnected". I have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Windows → Devices and Simulators (Shortcut key: cmd+shift+2)
2. You’ll see apple TV device connected to system with message:

> apple TV is busy: Copying cache files from device (or Preparing debugger support, etc)

3. Click on plus button (+) present in bottom-left corner.
   [step 3 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HRAi.png)
4. This will show the devices connected to system. Choose your apple tv device and click on Next button.
5. Thereafter you’ll see ‘device setup was successful’. Click on Done button.

That's helped for me.

Comment: This seems very similar to "Solution 3" in the answer by [Jayprakash Dubey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1753005) to [Xcode 9 “iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47448911/12695027)