# flutter stuck on Compiling, linking and signing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter project is stuck in `Compiling, linking and signing...` i dont just understand why this is stuck here...

even using `verbose` i dont get any stack trace on why this is stuck...

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             11.6s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...
```

[image]

Comment: For how much time are you waiting? For me it is almost normal to wait at least 10 minutes, and sometimes 15 for the compilation, and the issue can also be caused by a slow internet connection

Comment: @FrancescoPenasa more than 1 hour, this waiting is abnormal.. is taking too much time. i am very sure is will still be like this till the next day...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're experiencing the same cause as I did, but in my case, the issue was this line in my Podfile (`/ios/Podfile`)

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

(I don't remember why I had it there, it's not part of the default setup. I think I had added it as part of a solution for an older problem, but it's no longer necessary.)

I changed it back to the default:

```
use_frameworks!
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be in the existing project created on previous environment (old versions) and has to be resolved by creating a new one and moving content in.

Move all my custom contents from existing my project (assets, fonts, lib folders and config files...) to this new project and ran the command : the flutter build ios command works well now !

Answer (score 0):

following this : [Fixing Xcode 9 issue: "iPhone is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316373/fixing-xcode-9-issue-iphone-is-busy-preparing-debugger-support-for-iphone)

I TRIED :

1. On Xcode:

> Go to "Window" -> "Devices and Simulators"
> "Unpair iPhone" (on the side list, right clic)

2. Then:
   Unplug and plug again the USB cable
   Press Trust in the prompt message in the device
3. in Flutter Terminal, paste and enter :
   flutter clean
   flutter pub get
   cd ios
   pod install --repo-update
   cd ..
4. Then run the app.

==> Worked only 1st time for me.

My work around for launching IOS devices for now:
Each time I want IOS device,
I COPY/ PASTE and press ENTER on the Terminal:

flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install --repo-update
cd ..
flutter run

Answer (score 0):

For me running `flutter clean && flutter run` did it, as usual.

**Notice:** before running that I restarted the phone simulator just in case but I don't know if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case such error was caused by bugs in flutter 3.16.4. I downgraded to 3.16.0 and the error disappeared.